# Table value not being echoed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and am struggling with something.

The table has "link" and "rating" as columns and I'm selecting a row randomly from the table.

```
<?php
    $select = mysqli_select_db($conn, "database"); 
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");       
?>
```

If I add

```
while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row['rating']; };
```

directly underneath the `$result2`, it is echoed properly. But that's not where I want it. I have a whole bunch of HTML code after it, as well as more php tags too.

It needs to go in a header `<h1>` tag that's numerous lines beneath the code written above.

```
<h1> <?php while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row['rating']; }; ?> </h1>
```

And nothing is echoed inside the `h1` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you have there other SQL queries - you forgot to mention that.

Save the result of SQL query into variable and then just write this variable.

```
<?php
$result2 = ...; // SQL query
$row = $result2->fetch_assoc(); // no while loop necessary if you hav ejust one records from database
$rating = $row['rating'];
...
?>
...
<h1><?php echo $rating; ?></h1>
```